# Prevent wear notification using PlaybackStateCompat

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, wear-os

Following [this tutorial](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/background-audio-in-android-with-mediasessioncompat--cms-27030), I've implemented an audio player in my app.  However, a notification automatically displays on a Wear device, which I don't want.  I've narrowed it down to this code:

```
    PlaybackStateCompat.Builder playbackstateBuilder = new PlaybackStateCompat.Builder();

    if (state == PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PLAYING) {
        playbackstateBuilder.setActions(PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PLAY_PAUSE | PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PAUSE);
    } else {
        playbackstateBuilder.setActions(PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PLAY_PAUSE | PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PLAY);
    }

    playbackstateBuilder.setState(state, PlaybackStateCompat.PLAYBACK_POSITION_UNKNOWN, 0);
    mMediaSessionCompat.setPlaybackState(playbackstateBuilder.build());
```

specifically the last line is where the notification displays.  If I comment out that line, the notification doesn't display, however my app doesn't respond to external media controls anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`setPriority`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setPriority(int)) method in [`NotificationCompat.Builder`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html) to control your Android wear notifications instead.

In setting the priority, low-priority notifications may be hidden from the user in certain situations, while the user might be interrupted for a higher-priority notification.

See [Creating a Notification for Wearables](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/notifications/creating.html) for more information.